# Mediawiki widget will not run javascript

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am having a ridiculous problem which seems to be a lot harder than it really should be.

Have been struggling now for about three days trying to figure out a way to run javascript on pages in wikipedia, and it seems like it is close to impossible. (I can get it to run under common.js, but want it only on specific pages.

Seemed like one option is to use Widgets, but whenever I put script in, mediawiki changes it and removes the <> (changes it to &lt and &gt), which means it will not run, and I can't find a single mentioning anywhere how to get Mediawiki to stop doing this for Mediawiki or for the Widget extension. Any help would be welcome.

As an example, I put the following code in widget:redbox

```
    <noinclude>
This is a test
</noinclude>
<includeonly><script> type="text/javascript"> console.log("I am alie"); </script></includeonly>
```

And what I get back is

```
This is a test fckLR &lt;script&gt; type="text/javascript"> console.log("I am alie"); &lt;/script&gt;fckLR
```

Comment: If you run this on a centos machine, likely hood is that apache can't write to compile_templates, mediawiki fails to provide a useful error message though, so took me about half a day to figure this out . If mediawiki:widgets are correctly installed, the code <includeonly><script> type="text/javascript"> console.log("I am alie"); </script></includeonly> should work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to put a script in `common.js` that will only run if an element with a certain ID exists on the page (i.e. `$( '#some-id' ).length > 0`).

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody pointed out what I'm about to say, I am probably missing something... Also I know this post is very old, but is there a reason for `type=text/javascript` not to be inside the opening `script` tag?

I really fail to see why placing attributes outside the opening tag could be useful.

Just in case this was really a mistake and that's all there is to it, the correct syntax would be

```html
<includeonly>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("Hello, underworld!");
  </script>
</includeonly>
```